# Is there any way to disable INT 21h in emu8086?

Tags: assembly, emu8086

I'm having a problem when I'm coding a program in emu8086 that controls traffic lights system that have 2 modes, auto and manual. Everything seems ok until my teacher wants me to create a switch to manual from auto, which takes input from user. That's where the problem happens... The program will stop to wait for the input.

Here's the code:

```
#start=Traffic_Lights.exe#

name "traffic"

data segment
    mes db 'Press 1 for all red, 2 or 3 for maunal mode, 4 for auto mode, 5 to stop the program $'
    buffer db 10, 0
    timeout db 0
             
;                FEDC_BA98_7654_3210
situation dw 0000_0011_0000_1100b
s1        dw 0000_0010_1000_1010b
s2        dw 0000_1000_0110_0001b
s3        dw 0000_1000_0110_0001b
s4        dw 0000_0100_0101_0001b    

sit_end = $
;            FEDC_BA98_7654_3210
all_red  equ 0000_0010_0100_1001b
all_off  equ 0000_0000_0000_0000b
s5        dw 0000_1000_0110_0001b
s6        dw 0000_0011_0000_1100b
s7        dw 0000_0100_1001_0010b
data ends

code segment
    assume cs:code, ds:data

start:
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax 

    ; Disable "int 21h" interrupt
    
    lea dx, mes
    mov ah, 9
    int 21h       

    mov ax, all_off
    out 4, ax

    mov ax, all_red
    out 4, ax

input:
    mov ah, 01h    ; Read character from keyboard
    int 21h        ; AL contains the ASCII code of the pressed key
    ;Manual
    ;turn off all light
    cmp al, '0'
    je turn_off_lights
    
    ;turn on all red light
    cmp al, '1'
    je turn_on_red_lights 
    
 
    cmp al, '2'
    je turn_on_x_axis_lights

    cmp al, '3'
    je turn_on_y_axis_lights

    cmp al,'4'
    je automatic_mode
    
    cmp al, '5'
    je endd

    jmp input      ; Repeat input until a valid key is pressed

turn_off_lights:
    mov ax, all_off
    out 4, ax
    jmp input

automatic_mode:
    mov si, offset situation

next_situation:

    mov ax, [si]
    out 4, ax
    
    
DELAY_LOOP:


    mov ah, 1
    mov cx, 4Ch    ; 5 million microseconds
    mov dx, 4B40h
    mov ah, 86h
    int 15h
    
    mov ah, 01h
    int 21h 
    cmp al, '5'
    jnz start


    add si, 2
    cmp si, sit_end
    jb next_situation
    mov si, offset situation
    jmp next_situation




turn_on_red_lights:
    mov ax, all_red
    out 4, ax
    jmp input



turn_on_x_axis_lights:
    mov ax, s1
    out 4, ax

    mov cx, 4Ch    ; 5 million microseconds
    mov dx, 4B40h
    mov ah, 86h
    int 15h

    mov ax, s5
    out 4, ax
    jmp input

turn_on_y_axis_lights:
    mov ax, s4
    out 4, ax

    mov cx, 4Ch    ; 5 million microseconds
    mov dx, 4B40h
    mov ah, 86h
    int 15h

    mov ax, s6
    out 4, ax
    jmp input


endd:
code ends
end start
```

Comment: `int 21h` is a software interrupt, if you don't want it occur, just don't call `int 21h`.  What problem are you trying to solve by "disabling" `int 21`? Or what do you mean by "disable"?

Comment: `int 21h` isn't called **unless you call it**. Try using BIOS interrupt `int 16h fn 01h` "Read Keyboard Status" first. It's non blocking. Then read the key input with `int 16h fn 00h`, which should be good for a single-key menu option.

Comment: The problem is I have an infinite loop and I want to have a button that if it is pressed in 5 seconds time the program will exit the loop and jump back onto the start. But when the program checks for the input, the loop will stop until a key is pressed, not for 5 seconds

Comment: That is why I suggested using different functions. My DOS book says of `int 21h fn 1` "If no character is available at STDIN, this function will wait until one is available."

Comment: Ahhh I tried your solution earlier on but something happened and the code didn't run as I want but I've just fixed it and everything seems to be ok. Thanks a lot for your advice!

Comment: I can see where the confusion lies, it's called an "interrupt" which is a bit of a misnomer if you're used to phrases like "non-maskable interrupt" or "interrupt request" which take control away from your program regardless of what line of code is currently executing. `int 21h`, etc. are called by the user, if you don't have `int 21h` in your code it won't happen.